# How to refactor if blocks with repeated conditions?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Let's say I have some 6 conditions (a-f) and if statements listed below. As you can see there is a pattern for these if statements. Every next if statement has almost the same conditions as the previous one but the first condition which was used previously is removed.

```
    if(a && b && c && d && e && f)
      return 5;
    if(b && c && d && e && f)
      return 4;
    if(c && d && e && f)
      return 3;
    if(d && e && f)
      return 2;
    if(e && f)
      return 1;
    if (f)
      return 0;
    return -1;
```

I think there is no need to have so many elaborate conditions, especially as there are cases which introduce some redundant condition checks and I would prefer to avoid that. I've tried to rewrite it, but I've only come up with something like this:

```
    let res = -1;
    if(f) {
      res = 0;
      if(e) {
        res = 1;
        if(d) {
          res = 2;
          if(c) {
            res = 3;
          } if(b) {
            res = 4;
            if(a) {
              res = 5;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return res;
```

This way I no longer have redundant condition checks, but this solution still looks overcomplicated. Are there some clever ways to rewrite it so that I can have a simple solution without redundant checks?

Comment: `return (a + b + c + d + e + f) - 1`? What exactly are those conditions, and what combinations can occur? It might help if you could post your actual, real-world code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nested `if` statements aren't that bad - they get rid of the duplication quite efficiently, and create a linear structure! You can further shorten the code by using a loop:

```
let res = -1;
for (const flag of [f, e, d, c, b, a]) {
    if (flag) res++;
    else break;
}
return res;
```

This still evaluates all the conditions up-front, so if they are costly to compute you might want to use functions that you can evaluate when needed:

```
let res = -1;
for (const getFlag of [()=>f, ()=>e, ()=>d, ()=>c, ()=>b, ()=>a]) {
    if (getFlag()) res++;
    else break;
}
return res;
```

If the conditions are cheap, and you also know that if one is false all the remaining ones are false as well, you don't even need to `break` the loop. It can then be simplified into a single expression:

```
return -1 + f + e + d + c + b + a;
```

Comment: Thank you! The solutions with breaks are exactly what I needed. I should have clarified that there might be cases where for example f, e and a are true, because in such cases the one-line solution is no good for me.

Answer (score 0):

Put the conditions into an array, along with the results.

```
const conds = [[a, 5], [b, 4], [c, 3], [d, 2], [e, 1], [f, 0]];
while (conds.length) {
  if (conds.every(([cond]) => cond)) {
    return conds[1];
  }
  conds.shift();
}
return -1;
```

Comment: Nah, that's as inefficient as the OP's first snippet.